# Is there another way around to make redirection page?

Tags: php, mysql

Do I correctly do it? using header("Location: ....") to redirect to another page?

Could you suggest to improve may code because I'm new to this things..

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$msg='';
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password ='".$password."'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if($count == 1)
    {
        header("Location: AdminDeleteAccount.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
         $msg='Username and Password didnt match';
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);
}
else
{
    echo 'howdie';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that looks OK. I would recommend that passwords should **not** be stored in plain text format, at the very least they should be hashed (users tend to use the same password on multiple sites and if your database is hacked, then not only what data you store is compromised but all of your users passwords are as well).

Comment: oww I really don't know that.. thnks..

Answer (score 0):

yes you are doing it correctly, store the password in database using some kind of encrytption like MD5, sh1 etc. Also make sure that nothing is echoed out before the `header` function or else the header `function` will not work and you will see an error message.